# Getting the offset value for a user selection with momentjs?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

In my web application i have users select a certain time consisting of hours, minutes and a certain timezone.

The user selection is to trigger a function on my webserver at a certain time. But given that the user may select 11:00 in timezone "Europe/London", i need to account for the time difference between the time on my webserver and the triggering time and timezone selected by the user somehow, and calculate what the UTC version of the user selection would be.

The actual date is not important to me in this project, only that the triggering hour and minute needs to be adjusted so that a timed trigger function on my webserver matches the actual selection of time that the user has selected.

Any tips on how to achieve this using momentjs would be a great help ?

Comment: Questions of this sort have been asked and answered many times over.  Search the [tag:timezone] tag please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `moment.utc` to convert all dates to UTC and then use `date1.diff(date2, "hours")` to get the diff in hours (or use minutes, seconds for more accuracy)